# Unable to import EC2 instance with pulumi import command

Tags: go, pulumi

I am running an EC2 instance on aws which I need to import to pulumi by running the following command `pulumi import -f resources.json`.
I have the following JSON file as my resource file `resource.json`.

```json
{
  "resources": [{
    "type": "aws:ec2/instance:Instance",
    "name": "my-server",
    "id": "i-08f92a261a2ef6650",
    "ami": "ami-0fdb3f3ff5d7c40db"
  }
  ]
}
```

But get the following error:

```
aws:ec2:Instance (my-server):
error: aws:ec2/instance:Instance resource 'my-server' has a problem: Missing required argument: "instance_type": one of `instance_type,launch_template` must be specifie
d. Examine values at 'Instance.InstanceType'.
error: aws:ec2/instance:Instance resource 'my-server' has a problem: Missing required argument: "launch_template": one of `ami,instance_type,launch_template` must be sp
ecified. Examine values at 'Instance.LaunchTemplate'.
error: aws:ec2/instance:Instance resource 'my-server' has a problem: Missing required argument: "ami": one of `ami,launch_template` must be specified. Examine values at
'Instance.Ami'.
error: Preview failed: one or more inputs failed to validate
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, please see this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/issues/1605

and this one: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/7160#issuecomment-912093311

The best workaround at this stage is to define the EC2 instance in your code, and then set the `import` resource property as defined [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/import/#pulumi-import-resource-operation)

Comment: Thank you guess am gonna have to settle for creating my own instances